# Add arrow down css to the radius button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a radius button and want to add an arrow down icon inside this button.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.test {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: #444444;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#ffffff;
}
.down {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 6px;
  left     : 10px;
  width    : 0;
  height   : 0;
  z-index  : 100;
  border-left   : 10px solid transparent;
  border-right  : 10px solid transparent;
  border-top : 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test  ">
  <div class="down"> </div>
</div>
```

Just in case the snippet doesn't work, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v783us3w/) is a fiddle.

Why isn't the arrow inside the button?

Here's what I want:

[image: Image of desired result]

Comment: Well for starters, your fiddle misses the class `.down`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v783us3w/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.test {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background: #444444;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.down {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test ">
 <div class="down"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know how to show an arrow,you can use Boot Strap by adding it's  reference on top of your HTML code and use it's components:

```css
.test {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background: #444444;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
    
}

.down-arrow{
  margin-top:7px;
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down down-arrow" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

there is another simple way,in which you can use font awesome components ,check it out on google

Answer (score 0):

try using `postion:relative; maring:0px auto;` for `down` class